# Is there a way to find out how much data a certain query will process in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I need to export certain columns from a table in Mysql and have a limitation as to the final export size. Is ther a way to find out how much data will be processed by a certain query so I can have an understanding which columns I can exclude from export to meet the limitation?

I tried using EXPLAIN but it doesn't show this information.

Comment: Depends on your output format. A CSV is going to use fewer bytes than a PDF.

Comment: I need to understand how much data stored in MySql will be processed by a query. I guess I can have an approximate understanding of how much data can be exported. I have a table that is almost 300 GB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the byte size of resultset in an SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524019/how-to-get-the-byte-size-of-resultset-in-an-sql-query)