# How to get amount of data transfered between PHP and DB server from inside PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to analyze the amount of traffic certain scripts use when communicating with DB. I use `mysqli_connect`, then I do `mysqli_query` and then usually `mysqli_fetch_assoc` or `mysqli_fetch_array`. I want to know how many bytes are transferred for any given query. This will of course depend on how many times I call "fetch" methods. I can easily keep counters and sum them up, but how to get the correct values?

The best thing I can think of is calculate size of array returned by these fetch functions. Given that there is no byte_size_of() function in PHP, Id have to `foreach` through them and sum `strlen()` of every single value. But this obviously is bad approach, since these values wont be exactly what is received.

Thanks for help!

Note: the answers in [How to calculate size from my query MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562024/how-to-calculate-size-from-my-query-mysql) or [How to get the byte size of resultset in an SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524019/how-to-get-the-byte-size-of-resultset-in-an-sql-query) do not answer how to get it from PHP. I cant edit eveyr query and do it this way, I need a way to get file size from withing the PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function has `bytes_sent` and `bytes_received` in the output

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-connection-stats.php